# When is it safe to free a FP * in a Excel XLL?

Tags: c++, c, xll

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687840.aspx?ppud=4):

> ... Therefore, when returning a DLL-created string or floating-point
>   array, you have the following choices:
>
> - Set a persistent pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer, return the pointer. On the next call to the function (1) check that the
>     pointer is not null, (2) free the resources allocated on the previous
>     call and reset the pointer to null, (3) reuse the pointer for a newly
>     allocated block of memory. ...

I get the following error dialog when I call free:

> MSVC++ Debug Library HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal
>   block(#135) at 0x....... CRT detected that the application wrote to
>   memory after end of healp buffer.

Here's my code:

```
FP * g_FP;

extern "C" FP * __stdcall xllFill(long rows, long cols) {

    if (g_FP != NULL) {
        free(g_FP);
        g_FP = NULL;
    }
    g_FP = (FP *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double) + 2 * sizeof(unsigned short int));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        (*g_FP).data[i] = (double)i;
    }
    (*g_FP).rows = (unsigned short int)rows;
    (*g_FP).cols = (unsigned short int)cols;
    return g_FP;
}
```

I'm a bit rusty on C++ but I can't figure for the life of me why this isn't working.

Comment: Do you ever initialize g_FP before freeing it If not, you're freeing a wild pointer.

Comment: @San Jacinto it's declared global and will be initialised to NULL. Would be better to do that explicitly though IMV.

Comment: More accurately, it has static storage duration and will thus be zero-initialised. However, `NULL` pointers on your system may not necessarily have byte value "0" (even though we write `void* ptr = 0`, that `0` is not necessarily the value on disk). You should write `FP* g_FP = 0;` or `FP* g_FP = NULL;`.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: [dcl.init] ¶5: "if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression,
converted to `T`" - I think that this means that zero-initialization is perfectly equivalent to `FP* g_FP = (FP*)0;`, so your consideration about the actual byte value should not apply here (although I do prefer to explicitly initialize globals anyway).

Comment: @Matteo: Oh, hmm... OK, I agree. :)

Comment: And of course I meant "in memory" not "on disk"... lol

Comment: Of course since this is an XLL we don't need to get too excited about extreme portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FP` is declared like this:

```
typedef struct _FP
{
    unsigned short int rows;
    unsigned short int columns;
    double array[1];        /* Actually, array[rows][columns] */
} FP;
```

You are assuming that `FP` is packed and contains no padding. I don't know how XLLs are meant to be compiled but I think it is very likely that there is padding between `columns` and `array` to arrange that `array` is 8 byte aligned. With default settings, MSVC returns 16 for `sizeof(FP)` which supports my hypothesis.

Change your allocation to this:

```
g_FP = malloc((rows*cols-1)*sizeof(double) + sizeof(*g_FP));
```

Even if this isn't the cause of your problem, the allocation above is the logically correct form.

Otherwise I cannot see anything wrong with your code. I think you could be more explicit in initialising `g_FP` to `NULL` but that's a minor point.

Comment: Exactly my analysis. Many thx (although I think you beat me to pressing the send key by a minute ;o) )

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had you by 11 minutes!  ;-)

Comment: As an aside I think I would only do the free/malloc if the new value for `rows*cols` is greater than the previous value. That saves hitting the heap allocator more than needed.

Comment: My browser told me there was an answer whilst I was writing it up ;o). Either way a bit embarrasing!!!

Comment: Not embarrassing at all. We all do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(FP)` is 16, because rows and cols end up being aligned (presumably). I don't allow for this in my manual size calculation.

Better code would be:

```
g_FP = (FP *)malloc(sizeof(sizeof(FP) - sizeof(double) + rows * cols * sizeof(double)); // -sizeof(double) to account for the double[1] already in the struct def.
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some trouble and use the FP class from http://nxll.codeplex.com. The documentation for it is http://nxll.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FP.